# Multithreading using a Handler doesn't run past first pass

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler, runnable

I am trying to run a simple clock in my activity, the purpose of the project is to create a secondary thread to run our clock on and update our main UI thread using a handler. I thought I had it working but I guess I was looking at something wrong. Either way, here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Runnable{

/** VARIABLES **/
private LinearLayout currView;
private TextView clock;
private Typeface icelandFace;
private Calendar cal;

// clock time values
private int clockMins;
private int clockHour;
private int timeOfDay;      // am/pm
private String currTimeString;

// for alarm clock
boolean startAlarm = false;
private long alarmStartTime = -1;
private final int DESIRED_ALARM_DURATION = 5;

// clock thread handler, to communicate between our main ui and our secondary ui
// - note to self - rather unclear on the explanation for the suppression for the handler
private Handler handler = new Handler();

// runnable variable for the secondary thread to actually run on
private final Runnable clockRunnable = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        updateUI();
    }
};


/** OVERRIDDEN CLASS METHODS **/
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    currView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_activity);
    clock = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.clock_view);
    clock.setTextSize(clock.getTextSize() * 2);
    icelandFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/Iceland-Regular.ttf");
    clock.setTypeface(icelandFace);

    cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    // Create New Thread (to run our clock on)
    Thread clockThread = new Thread(){
        public void run() {         
            keepTime();
            clockMins = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            clockHour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
            timeOfDay = cal.get(Calendar.AM_PM);

            // Implement the handler for the thread
            // NOTE: recall, Message contains data and is passed to our handler
            //Message message = handler.obtainMessage();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                 // start with hours
                String timeString = clockHour + ":";
                // add minutes
                if(clockMins < 10){
                    timeString = timeString + "0" + clockMins + " ";
                }
                else{
                    timeString = timeString + clockMins + " ";
                }
                // set time of day
                if(timeOfDay == 0){
                    timeString = timeString + "am";
                }
                else{
                  timeString = timeString + "pm";
                }

                // Optional bundle stuff
                //bundle.putString("time_string", timeString);
                //message.setData(bundle);

                Log.d("Runnable", "Tracking time @ " + timeString);
                currTimeString = timeString;
                handler.post(clockRunnable);
        }

        private void keepTime(){   
            clockMins = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            clockHour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
            timeOfDay = cal.get(Calendar.AM_PM);

            checkAlarm(clockHour, clockMins, timeOfDay);        
        }

        private void checkAlarm(int hour, int min, int timeOfDay){
            SharedPreferences alarmPref = getSharedPreferences("alarm_preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);

            int alarmHour = alarmPref.getInt("alarm_hour", -1);
            int alarmMin = alarmPref.getInt("alarm_min", -1);
            int alarmTimeOfDay = alarmPref.getInt("alarm_time_of_day", 0);
            boolean alarmOn = alarmPref.getBoolean("alarm_on", true);

            if(hour == alarmHour && min == alarmMin && timeOfDay == alarmTimeOfDay && alarmOn == true
                    && alarmStartTime != -1){
                startAlarm = true;
            }
            return;
        }
    };
    clockThread.start(); 
}

//TODO: Setup the alarm via the menu that inflates here
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.alarm, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.alarm_settings:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, AlarmPopup.class));
            Toast.makeText(this, "Open Up Alarm Dialog", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}    


@Override
public void run()
{
    while (clockRunnable != null)
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) { };
        handler.post(clockRunnable);
    }
}


/** PRIVATE METHODS FOR SIMPLIFICATION **/
private void updateUI(){
    if(startAlarm == true){
        //AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmStartTime = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        currView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }
    else if((cal.get(Calendar.SECOND) - alarmStartTime) > DESIRED_ALARM_DURATION){
        alarmStartTime = -1;
        startAlarm = false;
        currView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    clock.setText(currTimeString);
}
```

Obviously I am missing something as far as grasping what is going on, but I can't tell what. Create a background thread, run your processes, pass it through the handler to control the variables, and send those variables through your UI update. I used http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/commontasks.html to gain that understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making the activity implement Runnable, try this:

```
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(clockRunnable);
        }
    };
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(task, 0, 1000);
```

Even though I would use a different approach registering a BroadcastReceiver to receive tick actions from the system (every second).
Regards.

Comment: Thank you for the response, have a link for the BroadcastReceiver by chance?

Comment: You can check the Intent reference at http://developer.android.com and check for ACTION_TIME_TICK for receiving changes in time every minute as your clock seems to need.
The previous suggestion I made is to construct your own broadcast (from a service for instance) and send it in the interval you need. Right now you only have an Activity acting as a holder for your clock, but you may wanna construct a widget afterwards to be able to display the time in the home activity.
If you’re doing it for learning purposes, that’s alright. Otherwise, reconsider the structure of your app.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I ended up going the BroadcastReceiver route, thank you very much for pointing me in that direction. Much, much smoother.

Comment: Always try to do a profiling to save resources in your app. As you can see, minimum conception changes result in great improvements. You're welcome.